# Who is the boy in the coffin in the last episode (of the Gemini of the Meteor)?

Tags: darker-than-black

Who is the boy in the coffin that wakes up in the last episode of the second season, *Gemini of the Meteor*? What significance does he play? Why does he look like Yin?

[image: Who? Who? Who?]

Answer (score 2):

If it's sticking vaguely close to the manga it's Kagutsuchi (the being unknown) who is created when Izanami (Yin) and Izanagi (Hei or Shion) bond as predicted in the [Mikata Documents](http://darkerthanblack.wikia.com/wiki/Mikata_Documents).

> Izanagi gazes upon the false sea bottom, waiting for Izanami. Izanami
>   will cross the sea bottom and eventually the two will meet. When they
>   do, heaven and earth will split in two, and there the Gate of Hell
>   will open. From the Gate will come forth one, a being unknown. And
>   strife will continue for eternity.

Comment: why do you have a blockquote and no link?

Comment: Didn't think it necessary since the entire plot of the 2nd season revolves around the quote.

Comment: What manga?  According to [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/3492/1421) there is no manga that follows the storyline of Gemini.

Answer (score 0):

The Russian boy's power is to create copies.  He created the Russian girl as a clone of himself.  They noted that one thing was always different in his clones; in the case of the Russian girl, it was the gender.

The same thing happened with the boy in the picture.  It's a clone of Yin with the gender switched. The Russian boy created a copy of the Earth, as I understand it, and on that copy earth, there is also a Yin.